# DryIoc call service method upon resolution

Tags: dryioc

How can I make DryIoc resolve `Service` as usual and immediately afterwards let it call its `Adjust( int )` method with some specific parameters?

**UPDATE**: Based on suggestion provided by *dadhi*, the code is changed to use `RegisterInitializer`

```cs
public interface IMaster
{
  void Run( int val );
}
public class Master : IMaster
{
  public Master( IService service )
  {
    service_ = service;
  }
  public void Run( int val )
  {
    service_.Execute( val );
  }

  private readonly IService service_;
}

public interface IService
{
  void Execute( int val );
}

public class Service : IService
{
  public void Adjust( int state ) // This method does not belong to the interface
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Service state is adjusted with {0}", state );
    state_ = state;
  }

  public void Execute( int val )
  {
    var result = val + state_;
    Console.WriteLine( "Service execution resulted in {0}", result );
  }

  private int state_;
}

static void Main( string[] args )
{
  var container = new Container();

  container.Register<Service>( Reuse.Singleton );
  container.RegisterInitializer<IService>( ( service, resolver ) =>
                                           { // Casting type down is a bad idea.
                                             ( (Service)service ).Adjust( 5 );
                                           } );

  container.Register<IMaster, Master>( Reuse.Singleton,
                                       Parameters.Of.Type<IService>( typeof( Service ) ) );

  var master = container.Resolve<IMaster>();

  master.Run( 10 );
}
```

The code above utilizes type cast which is, firstly, dirty enough to be blocked by our code quality standards.

Secondly, another registration may happen to map `IService` to `AlternativeService`, which has nothing to do with Adjust method.

So the question is why can I not replace `container.RegisterInitializer<IService>` with `container.RegisterInitializer<Service>`?
   If I do this initialization code does not get called.

And more generally, is there any way to achieve what I want without explicit type casts? It would be great if we could link initialization to concrete classes rather than to interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You may need [RegisterInitializer](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#registerinitializer) method.

Comment: I tried RegisterInitializer but did not immediately realize that it has to be called in addition to rather than instead of regular registration. My silly mistake.

Comment: After calling RegisterInitializer properly another issue emerged. Please take a look at the updated code and question.